# Mostrar solo los un elemento que no se repiten y los que se repiten sumarle al valor

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una aplicación hecha en c# con base de datos postgresql, dicha aplicacion es de vender loteria. Lo que necesito es que la consulta de base de datos me devuelva una vez el numero vendido.

Mi conuslta:

```c
string sql = "SELECT numero,total,reventado from tiquete ti , horario h where h.nombre_hora = ti.horario and ti.estado ='guardado' and ti.fecha ='" +fecha+"'and ti.horario='" +nombre+ "' order by numero asc";
```

Comment: Que es lo que te está devolviendo? Si un número puede venderse más de una vez, cada cuanto tiempo es que puede venderse sin repetirse? Es decir cada cuanto se sortea? Estaría bueno que agregues la respuesta de lo que te devuelve esa consulta para dar mas contexto.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: buenas si un numero puede venderse mas de una ves,digamos que yo vendi el 20 con 2 dolares,pero llega otra persona y me compra otra ves el 20 con 2 dolares y la consulta me de vuelve dos veces el 20 con dos dolares en ves de devolverme el 20 con 4 dolares.